# Alter form value in submit_preprocess

Tags: 8, forms, theming

How do I change a value, in this case the title field of a node object form, in the preprocess function of the form_alter hook.

```
$form['actions']['publish']['#submit'][] = MODULE_submit_preprocess';

function MODULE_submit_preprocess($form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {

   $form_state->setValue('title', 'Updated Title'); //not working...

   $fstate = $form_state->getFormObject()->getEntity();
   dsm($fstate);
}
```

**dsm result**

```
stdClass Object
(
    [__CLASS__] => Drupal\node\Entity\Node
    [in_preview] =>
    [values] => Array
        (
            [title] => Array
              (
                  [x-default] => Array
                    (
                         [0] => Array
                          (
                             [value] => Old Title
```

Comment: In this case, maybe it is better use `MODULE_ENTITY_presave()` function. After submit and before save in db, Drupal call this function then you can change something in your entity. If you want to change a node, then use `MODULE_node_presave()`. And will be called when you create and update.

Comment: That is a viable answer and accomplishes the task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change Entities fields its better use `MODULE_ENTITY_presave()` function (more info in [docs](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21entity.api.php/function/hook_entity_presave/8.0.x)).

In this case that you need change a node field use this function:

```
function hook_node_presave(Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityInterface $entity) {
  $entity->set('title', 'Updated title');
}
```

Comment: Then to change the title before saving to database: $entity->title='Updated Title';

Comment: I have a _utility_ field, populated via javascript, that was added in the form_alter hook that I use to set the field_date before submitting. The field only exists in $form_state and is not available to hook_presave. So I still need to know how to alter a value in the preprocess callback. I can add the field to the entity, but it would be nice to be able to do it in code.

Comment: I think that you can overthinking a problem, maybe there is another way much easier to do what you need. Back to your situation, maybe you can use `$fstate` that actually is your Node, and use `Node::setTitle`. In your question shows 'old value' because you just changing FormState object instead your Node.